Bulk Resize Images of Different Aspect Ratio so that all have Same Width
I am trying to resize multiple images inside of a folder so that all images have the same width, keeping aspect ratio. The images are all different sizes and aspect ratios. I don't care about the final aspect ratio of each image, so long as whatever their original aspect ratio was is mostly preserved.
When I type in magick mogrify -path webscale/ -resize 700x *.jpg, this causes the images to be resized so that the longest dimension is at 700 pixels long. e.g. Portrait orientation images are 700 pixels high. Landscape orientation images are 700 pixels wide. I have tried every single operator I could find int he documentation, '>, <, !, ^, @'. I have also tried 700x700, 700, x700, 700x10000, the issue also persists. I have tried using the convert command inside of a shell script.
I am at my wits end. I just want to resize the images so that every image, REGARDLESS of all other possible considerations, is 700 pixels wide. What am I doing wrong?

"Portrait orientation images are 700 pixels high" – Maybe they are really 700 pixels wide. I wonder if some orientation values come into play here.


causes the images to be resized so that the longest dimension is at 700 pixels long. e.g. Portrait orientation images are 700 pixels high. Landscape orientation images are 700 pixels wide

I think this happens because the input pictures were taken with a smartphone or tablet. When the user turns the device to Portrait orientation, the device doesn't rotate the image data; the device only applies an EXIF Orientation tag. In turn, if the program doing the resizing is EXIF-unaware, then what it "thinks" is the width of the image (to be scaled to 700 pixels, keeping the aspect ratio also) is actually the height of the image (per EXIF Orientation tag).
I've now written this small bash script (resize.sh) as an experiment; you might want to try it. It works with a tree of jpeg files, and "mirrors" the input file tree to an output directory (keeping the original tree structure). It is supposed to be run with find and GNU Parallel (see example invocation in the code comments), and requires the netpbm suite (package netpbm-progs on my system) and exiftool (package perl-Image-ExifTool on my system):
#!/bin/bash

# run with:
# find IN-DIR -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0 \
# | parallel -0 -r -n 1 -t -- ./resize.sh OUT-DIR NEW-WIDTH-IN-PIXELS

set -e -u -o pipefail

outdir="$1"
new_width="$2"
infile="$3"

outfile=$outdir/$infile
outdir=$(dirname -- "$outfile")
mkdir -p -- "$outdir"

orientation=$(exiftool -Orientation -S -n -- "$infile")

jpegtopnm -dct float -- "$infile" \
| case "$orientation" in
    ("Orientation: 8")
      pamflip -r90
      ;;
    ("Orientation: 3")
      pamflip -r180
      ;;
    ("Orientation: 6")
      pamflip -r270
      ;;
    ("Orientation: 2")
      pamflip -lr
      ;;
    ("Orientation: 7")
      pamflip -r90 | pamflip -lr
      ;;
    ("Orientation: 4")
      pamflip -r180 | pamflip -lr
      ;;
    ("Orientation: 5")
      pamflip -r270 | pamflip -lr
      ;;
    (*) cat
      ;;
  esac \
| pamscale -width "$new_width" \
| pnmtojpeg --dct=float --optimize > "$outfile"


What you do seems right, so I must admit I can't really help you solve your imagemagick problem.
Can't for the love of my sanity remember imagemagick command line's finer details, which is why I'm using graphicsmagick anyway (an earlier for of imagemagick, which tends to be slightly more sensible to use, has had fewer security problems and tends to be a lot faster. I suspect your problem is that magick mogrify misbehaves when called with multiple input files, differently than you expect when you use it on individual files. Also, I'd recommend you use convert rather than mogrify, as mogrify overwrites the original, by default (which could happen when you make a minor typo).
I am quite fond of graphicsmagick's batch command, it allows me to specify the operations I want graphicsmagick to do, without having to call it on every single file. You just feed in commands to its input and it does what you want:
for f in *.jpg; do
  printf 'convert -verbose "%s" -geometry 700x "%s"\n' "${f}" "webscale/${f}"
done | gm batch -echo on -feedback on - 

(pretty much stolen from the graphicsmagick documentation of batch)
Gere, the for loop just generates the command input to the one gm process, which then does what it would do on individual files, just without having to load all of the program for every single file.

You can use ffmpeg to do it, and maintain the proper AR.
for f in *.{jpg,png}; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf "scale=700:-1" resized-"${f#./}"; done

That will keep them scaled correctly, while making them all 700px wide. If you want height instead, just swap the values: -vf "scale=-1:700"
